# How to change label of tab bar item dynamically (IPhone dev)

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I'm using XCode 4.1 and I have an already existing IPhone app.

In the "MainWindow.xib", in the Interface builder, there is a Navigation Controller. Inside it, a Tab Bar Item with a title on it. I need to change this title dynamically. However, there seems to be no ".h" file associated with the MainWindow.xib, so I have no idea how to access this object. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main window or the tab bar bontroller was, somehow, related to another controller (associated with a .h and .m file).

So in this controller, I added this code :

```
UIViewController *uvButton1 = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
uvButton1.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", nil);
```

and so on for the 2 others (changing the index "0" for "1" and "2");

the `NSLocalizedString` function goes to a localized file (`Localizable.strings`) and chooses the right text based on the key. You can also just use a standard string there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a .h file to access items in MainWindow.xib. You can declare IBOutlets in your app delegate for the items you want to access. One of the objects in MainWindow.xib is the app delegate, so you can assign elementos to its IBOutlets.

Comment: I'm new to MACs and IOS development, so I don't really understand your solution. I see the object "App delegae" in the "Objects" pane of the MainWindow.xib.. What Am I supposed to do with that?